# Sync iCloud Photo Library to Mac while not logged in?

Tags: mac, icloud, photos

Is it possible to sync photos from the iCloud library to a Mac while not being logged in that Mac?

I am asking because I am using an old Mac as a server (always on) and would like to have a backup of my photos / my wife's photos and my daughter's photos  on that Mac?

Comment: I think it does.  I’m going to snap some pictures with my phone tonight and leave my Mac on but logged out. I’ll see if the folders synchronize.